# Cartoon with purple crystals/gems quest and a yeti-like character

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I have been looking for ages for a cartoon TV show about a protagonist (probably  a girl) looking for purple crystals/gems that have been hidden. She needs to get them before the villain does.

The only episode I remember is when they are at the place where the crystal is hidden with the yeti/hairy-looking guys, and one of these guys is traveling with the protagonist.

EDIT, more details:

So I am looking for a tv show that I watched around 1998-2001.

Young human girl (possibly a princess) traveling with 2  or more other characters. One of them is a big hairy guy ( from another planet? or atleast he is of some kind of another race). They are on a ship ( maybe spaceship ) searching for crystals. They are trying to get to the crystals before the villain does but are usually just too late and the villain gets to the crystals first.

The only episode i remember to any degree is the one where they are on the planet/place/city or at least the home place of the hairy guy where his people life. His people are keeping one of the crystals safe. The episode ends with the villain getting the crystal.
I watched this in iceland with icelandic dub.

There is also this one scene in the intro of the show where it zooms in on the villain where he is in his ship (possibly spaceship) unfortunately i dont remember why they are trying to find the crystals.

This is not Dark Crystal or any anime... :)

Comment: Hi there! Maybe yo could take a look at [these guidelines on story-ID questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if that triggers any more memories you could [edit] in? For instance, roughly when did you watch that? Do you remember which channels it was likely to have aired on? Was it in English, was it a translation? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for the input! I will edit the question :)